# Using withBackdrop for paper-dialog prevents controls from being focused via tabbing

Tags: html, polymer, accessibility, polymer-1.0, paper-dialog

I have a paper-dialog that uses the with-backdrop property. I've noticed that after clicking anywhere within a paper-dialog that **does not** use the with-backdrop property, I can hit the tab key and the browser will focus the input element:

```js
addEventListener('WebComponentsReady', function() {
  Polymer({
    is: 'x-example',
    ready: function() {
      this.$$('paper-dialog').open();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<base href="https://polygit.org/components/">
<script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
<link href="paper-dialog/paper-dialog.html" rel="import">
<link href="paper-input/paper-input.html" rel="import">
<link href="polymer/polymer.html" rel="import">

<dom-module id="x-example">
  <style>
    :host {
      display: block;
    }
  </style>
  <template>
    <paper-dialog>
      <h2 class="header">Hello</h2>
      <paper-input
        label="Focusable input"
        tabindex
        type="text">
      </paper-input>
    </paper-dialog>
  </template>
</dom-module>

<x-example></x-example>
```

If I set the with-backdrop property, however, the browser will not focus the input element:

```js
addEventListener('WebComponentsReady', function() {
  Polymer({
    is: 'x-example',
    ready: function() {
      this.$$('paper-dialog').open();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<base href="https://polygit.org/components/">
<script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
<link href="paper-dialog/paper-dialog.html" rel="import">
<link href="paper-input/paper-input.html" rel="import">
<link href="polymer/polymer.html" rel="import">

<dom-module id="x-example">
  <style>
    :host {
      display: block;
    }
  </style>
  <template>
    <paper-dialog with-backdrop>
      <h2 class="header">Hello</h2>
      <paper-input
        label="Focusable input"
        tabindex
        type="text">
      </paper-input>
    </paper-dialog>
  </template>
</dom-module>

<x-example></x-example>
```

Is there a way to have a backdrop and still allow the dialog to navigatable via the keyboard?

Device info: I am experiencing this issue running Chrome v50 on OSX.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be issue with versions that you are using. I tried it on Polymer's website and my local and this seems to be working fine. Below are the versions that i used:

Paper-dialog: 1.0.4

Polymer: 1.3.2

Paper-input: 1.0.18

I'll also recommend you to open up an issue on Github for the same

Comment: Thanks @a1626; ended up accidentally including a value-less tabindex property. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In the demo, I included the tabindex attribute in my input element without specifying a value. Removing this property allowed the input to be focused:

```js
addEventListener('WebComponentsReady', function() {
  Polymer({
    is: 'x-example',
    ready: function() {
      this.$$('paper-dialog').open();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<base href="https://polygit.org/components/">
<script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
<link href="paper-dialog/paper-dialog.html" rel="import">
<link href="paper-input/paper-input.html" rel="import">
<link href="polymer/polymer.html" rel="import">

<dom-module id="x-example">
  <style>
    :host {
      display: block;
    }
  </style>
  <template>
    <paper-dialog with-backdrop>
      <h2 class="header">Hello</h2>
      <paper-input
        label="Focusable input"
        type="text">
      </paper-input>
    </paper-dialog>
  </template>
</dom-module>

<x-example></x-example>
```